# Html for nested list, mixed number and bullet points

Tags: html, nested-lists

I need to come as close to the example below, using only html. I can get the top level numbered list and the next level of bullet points, but can't figure out how to get the most-indented level of bullet points.

If it can be done, please tell or point me to correct syntax. Thanks!

I've had to use "_"s to get the formatting to look right in the preview.

1. Top level point
   _• A subsidiary point
   ___• Sub point
   _• Next subsid. point
2. Next top level point

Answer (score 1):

if I understood your question, I think this is what you are looking for: [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/hqtj1cvL/2/)

```
<ol>
    <li>List item one</li>
        <ul>
            <li>Subitem 1</li>
        <ul>
            <li>Sub-Subitem 1</li>
        </ul>
        <li>Subitem 2</li>
        </ul>
    <li>List item two with subitems:</li>
</ol>
```

Comment: Appreciate the suggestion, but that's not quite what I'm looking for.


There are 3 levels total: the top level is numbered, the 2nd level is bulleted, and the 3rd level is bulleted. I can't figure out how to get the 3rd level correctly indented.

Comment: I just finished editing it to make it look like what you are looking for now, I think I got it right.

Comment: That looks right in dreamweaver, so I'll transfer it to the blog post I'm working on and see if it holds. Thank you!

Comment: It doesn't display in the wordpress blog the way it does in dreamweaver. Either it's the stylesheet interfering or I haven't got the syntax right...

Answer (score 1):

I guess this may help

```
<ol>
    <li>Outer 1
        <ul type="disc">
            <li>Inner 1
                <ul  type="disc">
                    <li>Sub Inner 1 </li>
                </ul>
              </li>
            <li>Inner 2</li>
        </ul>
    </li>
    <li>Outer 2</li>
</ol>
```

Answer (score 0):

try this

```
<ol>
<li>item 1</li>
<li>item 2
<ul>
    <li>Sub-item 1</li>
    <li>Sub-item 2</li>
    <li>Sub-item 3
    <ul>
    <li>sub-Subitem 1</li>
    <li>sub-Subitem 2</li>
    </ul>
    </li>
</ul>
</li>
<li>item 3</li>
```

Answer (score 0):

```
<ol>
<li>
    Top level point
    <ul style="list-style: disc;">
        <li>
            A subsidiary point
            <ul style="list-style: disc;">
                <li>Sub point</li>
            </ul>
        </li>
        <li>Next subsid. point</li>
    </ul>
</li>
<li>Next top level point</li>
```

How's this? Should be exactly what you described.
http://jsfiddle.net/hqtj1cvL/7/

Answer (score 0):

Is this what you looking for??

```html
<ol>
    <li>one</li>
    <li>two</li>
    <li>three</li>
    <ul>
        <li>one</li>
    <li>two</li>
        <ul>
            <li>one</li>
    <li>two</li>
            <li>three</li>
        </ul>
    <li>three</li>
    </ul>
    <li>four</li>
</ol>
```